# Which api I use to get Best Near By venues from foursquare

Tags: android, foursquare

**I want a api which foursquare android app uses in its app to get best near by venues.. If any know please help me..**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no prior research nor minimal understanding of the problem being solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search the venues near by you using the below Rest API..

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&v=20140730&locale=en&radius=1000&ll=LAT,LNG&limit=20&query=royal&categoryId=COMMA_SEPERATED_IDS

For more details, you can refer the link below:

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search

Also to fetch the specific category from the four square for COMMA_SEPERATED_IDS, you can get it from the below link:

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/categories

To create client id and client secret, follow below link:

https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth

Hope it will help you..!!!

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search) is the API you should use

> Search Venues https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search Returns a
>   list of venues near the current location, optionally matching a search
>   term.
>
> To ensure the best possible results, pay attention to the intent
>   parameter below. And if you're looking for "top" venues or recommended
>   venues, use the explore endpoint instead.
>
> If lat and long is provided, each venue includes a distance. If
>   authenticated, the method will return venue metadata related to you
>   and your friends. If you do not authenticate, you will not get this
>   data.
>
> Note that most of the fields returned inside venue can be optional.
>   The user may create a venue that has no address, city or state (the
>   venue is created instead at the geolat/geolong specified). Your client
>   should handle these conditions safely.
>
> You'll also notice a stats block that reveals some count data about
>   the venue. herenow shows the number of people currently there (this
>   value can be 0).